# How do I pass Data from action to action using mvc and not in router?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an action inside of users and I want that action to return the user to another action in another controller but not in the router parameter. Here is a sample

```
 public IActionResult LoginCheck(UserForm user)
        {
            AuthUser auth = new AuthUser(_context);
           var result = auth.IsLoggedIn(user.Email, user.Password);
            if(result.isfound==false)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            result.User.IsAuth = true;

            return RedirectToAction("Home","Index",result.User);
            

        }
```

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(User user)
        {
            if(user.IsAuth == false)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

just part of the code
```

Home index did not use the incoming user as it was sent as router parameters I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData to achieve that.

```
public IActionResult LoginCheck(UserForm user)
        {
            AuthUser auth = new AuthUser(_context);
           var result = auth.IsLoggedIn(user.Email, user.Password);
            if(result.isfound==false)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            result.User.IsAuth = true;
            TempData["user"] =  result.User;
            return RedirectToAction("Home","Index");
            

        }
```

Then you can get it in the other action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

              if(TempData["user"] == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }else{
             var someUser= (User)TempData["user"]; 
         }
}
```

But I do not recommend using TempData for sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use second action **as method**:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginCheck(UserForm user)
        {
            AuthUser auth = new AuthUser(_context);
           var result = auth.IsLoggedIn(user.Email, user.Password);
            if(result.isfound==false)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            result.User.IsAuth = true;

            return await Index(result.User);
            

        }
```

second action

```
[NonAction] //  Indicates that a controller method is not an action method.
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(User user)
{

           if(user == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
           else{
             var someUser= user; 
            }
}
```

Use redirection make browser to handle this transfer and it is slower.